# Sympy symbolic differential

Tags: python, sympy

So, I have a equation like this [image]. Now if I operate grad function on this it becomes like this

[image]

How do I do this on sympy? Sympy uses a reference frame but I didn't find any other than x,y,z, And I need multiple custom variable like this. Is it possible to do it in sympy?

Comment: There is nothing fully symbolic but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558515/how-to-get-the-gradient-and-hessian-sympy) may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify your theta variables to be functions, you can have something like this:

```
In [5]: A = theta12(x)*theta23(x)*theta13(x)

In [6]: A
Out[6]: θ₁₂(x)⋅θ₁₃(x)⋅θ₂₃(x)

In [7]: A.diff(x)
Out[7]: 
              d                          d                          d         
θ₁₂(x)⋅θ₁₃(x)⋅──(θ₂₃(x)) + θ₁₂(x)⋅θ₂₃(x)⋅──(θ₁₃(x)) + θ₁₃(x)⋅θ₂₃(x)⋅──(θ₁₂(x))
              dx                         dx                         dx
```

Notice that I'm using the ordinary derivative. For more variables, just use more variables (unfortunately it will distribute):

```
In [8]: A = theta12(x,y)*theta23(x,y)*theta13(x,y)

In [9]: A.diff([[x,y]])
Out[9]: 
⎡                    ∂                                   ∂                                   ∂                                  ∂         
⎢θ₁₂(x, y)⋅θ₁₃(x, y)⋅──(θ₂₃(x, y)) + θ₁₂(x, y)⋅θ₂₃(x, y)⋅──(θ₁₃(x, y)) + θ₁₃(x, y)⋅θ₂₃(x, y)⋅──(θ₁₂(x, y))  θ₁₂(x, y)⋅θ₁₃(x, y)⋅──(θ₂₃(x, 
⎣                    ∂x                                  ∂x                                  ∂x                                 ∂y        

                          ∂                                   ∂            ⎤
y)) + θ₁₂(x, y)⋅θ₂₃(x, y)⋅──(θ₁₃(x, y)) + θ₁₃(x, y)⋅θ₂₃(x, y)⋅──(θ₁₂(x, y))⎥
                          ∂y                                  ∂y           ⎦
```

There is a gradient operator but it's meant for usage in the `sympy.vector` module only.