# Define gradient and hessian function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I would like the compute the `Gradient` and `Hessian` of the following function with respect to the variables `x` and `y`. Anyone could help? Thanks a lot.

[image]

I find a code relevant from [github](https://github.com/mkozturk/notebooks/blob/master/Rosenbrock%2C%20steepest%20descent%2C%20decreasing%20step%20length.ipynb) for calculation of Rosenbrock function.

```
def objfun(x,y):
    return 10*(y-x**2)**2 + (1-x)**2
def gradient(x,y):
    return np.array([-40*x*y + 40*x**3 -2 + 2*x, 20*(y-x**2)])
def hessian(x,y):
    return np.array([[120*x*x - 40*y+2, -40*x],[-40*x, 20]])
```

**Update:**

```
from sympy import symbols, hessian, Function, N

x, y = symbols('x y')
f = symbols('f', cls=Function)

f = (1/2)*np.power(x, 2) + 5*np.power(y, 2) + (2/3)*np.power((x-2), 4) + 8*np.power((y+1), 4)

H = hessian(f, [x, y]).subs([(x,1), (y,1)])
print(np.array(H))
print(N(H.condition_number()))
```

Ouput:

```
[[9.00000000000000 0]
 [0 394]]
43.7777777777778
```

[How to get the Gradient and Hessian | Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558515/how-to-get-the-gradient-and-hessian-sympy)
https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/vector/fields.html

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: I don't know how to caculate `Hessian` and `Gradient` functions.

Comment: What do you want to tell us by showing the code you found for the other function? Can you not just replace the formula with your function?

Comment: Then look it up in a math book.

Comment: I update my question. Please check.

Comment: And what is the problem with the new code you've added? What output did you expect instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is the `hessian` function for expressions and the `jacobian` method for matrices.

Here are the function and variables of your problem:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> from sympy import ordered, Matrix, hessian
>>> eq = x**2/2 + 5*y**2 + 2*(x - 2)**4/3 + 8*(y + 1)**4
>>> v = list(ordered(eq.free_symbols)); v
[x, y]
```

We can write our own helper for gradient which will create a matrix and use the `jacobian` method on it:

```
>>> gradient = lambda f, v: Matrix([f]).jacobian(v)
```

Then the quantities can be calculated as:

```
>>> gradient(eq, v)
Matrix([[x + 8*(x - 2)**3/3, 10*y + 32*(y + 1)**3]])
>>> hessian(eq, v)
Matrix([
[8*(x - 2)**2 + 1,                  0],
[               0, 96*(y + 1)**2 + 10]])
```

Comment: Thank you. It generates: `NameError: name 'ordered' is not defined`, did I missed to import some packages?

Comment: Yes, @ahbon, you should also import `ordered` from `sympy.utilities.iterables`.

Comment: Shoudl I set `eq = x**2/2 + 5*y**2 + 2*(x - 2)**4/3 + 8*(y + 1)**4`? How to define `eq`?